# Trying to convert and display a collection of JSON format dates to normal format

Tags: javascript, json, angular, date

I am displaying 50 concert details on a page, which come from [an online JSON source](http://api.bandsintown.com/events/search.json?&api_version=2.0&app_id=FYP&location=Dublin,Ireland).

The date is in JSON format and I want to convert and display it in the normal format.

I was going down the route of acquiring by class name, converting and then appending; but I have hit a bit of a wall.

eventTimeConv is empty as I was going to append my converted date into there:

```
<div class = "eventTimeConv"></div>
<div id = "event-time" class = "event-date-time">{{ show.datetime }}</div>
```

The javascript I have written up so far:

```
function changeDate()
{
  var date = document.getElementsByClassName("event-date-time");

  var newDate = new Date(date);
  var dateConverted = newDate.toDateString();

  var div = document.getElementsByClassName("eventTimeConv");
}
```

The conversion to dateConverted fails due to 'date' being a collection I'm assuming.

Can anyone provide some guidance here? Or an alternate method?

Comment: there is no "JSON format" for dates...

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure of that, but thought that was what it was. What is the correct terminology?

Comment: @TyroneStock—just show the actual value, which seems to be `"datetime":"2017-04-19T17:00:00"`, which is ISO 8601 extended format.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) and [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

if you like to try momentjs then just format your date as-

```
<div class = "eventTimeConv"></div>
<div id = "event-time" class = "event-date-time">
  {{ moment(show.datetime).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm') }}
</div>
```

Comment: why you think like that?

Comment: I have tried this now, but my date divs are empty and no dates are being displayed

Comment: did you included momentjs library?

Comment: Yeah I did, I tried both CDN and now I have actually downloaded and included it as I wasn't trusting the CDN. I'd really like this to work, very clean

Answer (score 1):

GetElementsByClassName will return an array of all the divs with that class. So when you pass the date variable to new Date() function is not receiving a valid date string.

You will have to loop through that array and pick out the value you want to set to set the date for.

Comment: *getElementsByClassName* returns a live [*HTMLCollection*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#htmlcollection), which is Array-like, but it's not an Array.